# Simplifying the ip to connect to

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express, networking

i used express to host my html file. The hostname is full of random number which is my ip and it include the port. Example: `123.123.123.123:8080/main.html`. Ive used noip.com to try to make it `website.ddns.net` but getting the result of `website.ddns.net:8080/main.html`

Code:

```
const express = require('express')

var app = express()


app.use(express.static(__dirname))

app.listen(8080, function () {
  console.log('Example app listening on port 8080!')
})
```

Comment: can you provide some code like your express server serving your html file please ?

Comment: @mJehanno done hope you can help out

Comment: What URL do you want to connect to?  Please clarify exactly what question you're asking for help with.

Comment: i used `noip.com` to shorten the ip and i got the result of  `website.ddns.net:8080/main.html` how do i make it to something like just `website.ddns.net` ?

Comment: Check the [port 80 redirect](http://www.noip.com/support/knowledgebase/how-to-configure-your-no-ip-hostname/) settings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You actually don't want to serve your html file using `app.use(express.static(__dirname))`

instead you want to create a route like this :

`app.get("/",(req,res)=>{res.sendFile(pathToYourFile)});` as mentionned here : http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#res.sendFile

edit : you also probably want to change the port your listening on from 8080 to 80

Comment: How does this relate to their question? They never mentioned `this.header.append`, and they don't appear to be having any issues serving their static HTML.

Comment: failed copy paste ... read at least the rest of the answer before downvoting --" you'd have seen the sendFile and see what was the problem

Comment: That still doesn't answer their question - switching to using `sendFile` won't make any difference to whether or not they need an IP/port to access their site.

Comment: Your edit is correct, though - will remove my downvote! I'd recommend making that the focus of your answer, rather than the static file stuff.

Comment: the problem he has is not about his ip, his domain name point to the correct server but since he use express to serve a static file, he can only access it by `website.ddns.net:8080/main.html` but he want `website.ddns.net` so actually it does solve his problem